# Specify input directory for Laravel Elixir/SASS

Tags: laravel, sass, gulp, gulp-sass, laravel-elixir

I currently have my `resources/assets` directory structured a bit differently from normal as I want to have a number of "themes" in my project.

Currently I have the following structures:

```
resources/assets/theme-one/scss/*
resources/assets/theme-one/coffee/*
```

And

```
resources/assets/theme-two/scss/*
resources/assets/theme-two/coffee/*
```

Now I'm trying to build my `gulpfile.js` using Elixir (For theme-one currently) and I'm trying to specify the input directory for my SASS files.

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass(['app.scss'], 'public/theme-one/css/app.css');
});
```

Of course, the above code will look at the `resources/assets/sass` directory by default but I want to tell it to look in the `resources/assets/theme-one/scss` directory instead.

I've tried all kinds of different combinations to try and get it to work but it seems that no matter what I try, Elixir/gulp-sass is always trying to look in `resources/assets/sass` and I get `File not found: resources\assets\sass\app.scss` errors.

I've tried:

- Adding a third parameter, specifying the input directory
- Specifying a full path to the file in relation to my `gulpfile.js` i.e. `resources/assets/theme-one/scss/app.scss`
- Switching round the second and third parameters
- Digging into the source code (https://github.com/laravel/elixir/blob/master/tasks/sass.js and https://github.com/laravel/elixir/blob/master/GulpPaths.js) to try and find out how to specify an input directory.
- Prefixing the `app.scss` in parameter 1 with a `./` and full path (From the comment and the code starting at line 97 in `GulpPaths.js`, explaining that prefixing the path with a `./` would essentially skip the prefixing)

I'm having no luck at all. Any ideas?

The only "solution" I could think of would be to change my project structure back to how Elixir wants it, i.e. have `resources/assets/sass/theme-one/app.scss` and `resources/assets/coffee/theme-one/app.coffee` etc. but that's not something I want to do. If all else fails I suppose I could just bin Elixir and just use gulp as is.

**Edit**

I've now tried changing the `assetsPath` config item in my `gulpfile.js` like this:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir.config.assetsPath = "resources/assets/theme-one";
elixir.config.publicPath = "public/theme-one";

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass(['app.scss']);
});
```

I'm still getting `File not found: resources/assets/sass/app.scss`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the [default config](https://github.com/laravel/elixir/blob/master/Config.js) of Elixir (public and assets):

```
//in your gulp file : 
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir.config.assetsPath = "resources/assets/theme-one";
elixir.config.publicPath = "public/theme-one";

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
});

elixir.config.assetsPath = "resources/assets/theme-two";
elixir.config.publicPath = "public/theme-two";

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
});
```

Watch out, for older versions (before 3.0) of Elixir you need to override the [config](https://github.com/laravel/elixir/blob/2.0/Config.js) like so :

```
elixir.config.assetsDir = "resources/assets/theme-one";
elixir.config.publicDir = "public/theme-one";
```

As pointed out in the comments by [Jonathon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2244675/jonathon)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried what you've suggested and still getting `File not found: resources/assets/sass/app.scss`. I'll update my question with my current `gulpfile.js`

Comment: Try with `mix.sass('app.scss');` without brackets. Works fine for me

Comment: Never mind, I've found out the problem. I must have an older version of Elixir. My config has the options `assetsDir` and `publicDir` rather than `assetsPath` and `publicPath`. If you update your question to mention these two potential options, I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that I needed to put trailing slashes on my paths. Also, in addition to `elixir.config.publicDir` I had to set `elixir.config.cssOutput` and `elixir.config.jsOutput` as well to get it working as I wanted it.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)